# Save button is not visible when adding Script editor webpart for Promoted links

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I added around 10 promoted links to my sharepoint home site. Default they are in horizontal direction. Now, as per my requirement I need them in vertical direction. For this I navigated to Settings -> Edit page -> Add webpart -> Social  -> Script Editor webpart and added. I edited and added the code as :

```
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-promlink-body {width:170px}
  .ms-promlink-header {visibility:hidden}
< /style>
```

When I tried to save, there is no **Save** button visible on my page. Only Stop Editing is visible.

Please help me out, how can I make my promoted links vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the webpart should be enough. This saves your css. Stop editing is just the way to return to the page 'view'.

To place the links in vertical you are addressing the right class: ms-promlink-body

```
.ms-promlink-body{width: 100px;}
```

I tried this on my local machine and everything works as expected.I noticed that the page goes bananas due to the .ms-promlink-header {visibility:hidden} line. If you just want to hide the webpart title, go to the webpart properties > appearance and set the chrome type to "none" and you're good to go

And the reason is: add this to your page as a test:

```
.ms-promlink-header {background-color: blue;}
```

You'll see that the .ms-promlink-header-selector results in selecting the total iframe (with navigation options). So hiding it will indeed hide all promoted links.

Thus, you are better of changing the chrome type as suggested.

Comment: When I clicked on Stop editing, all the promoted links are invisible.

Comment: ok, i tried exactly the same thing locally and i now can reproduce your issue. I'll try to find a solution